# Is there a way to profile asset manifest by size?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I have a rails asset manifest that looks something like this:

applications.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require components

//= require_tree .
//= require_self
//= require react_ujs
```

I'm trying to figure out what the largest components are. Is there a way to easily list the sizes of each include?

Answer (score 0):

In development there's a flag `config.assets.debug` in your `config/environments/development.rb`, which is set to true by default. If it is so, then the required assets should load as separate files in development.

Then you can just open the Network tab in Chome Developer Tools, set the filter to JS, and seethe filesize of every asset file.